# ManageEntitlementState workflow in Dynamics 365 version 9

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Since Dynamics 365 version 9 upgrade, we have observed new workflows automatically created on CRM instance namely- *ManageContractLineState, ManageContractState, ManageEntitlementState*.

As I can see from the *ManageEntitlementState* workflow, it is to handle the status of entitlements in CRM. But earlier this was not done using CRM workflows. 
[image]
Now each workflow instance will be running for each entitlement in our system which is a huge problem since it puts unnecessary load on our machine.

Is anyone else able to see these workflows on their instances? And why is MS adding these workflows?

Comment: I couldn’t find any direct documentation related to this. As always MS documentation piece is little behind their deliveries. :)

Answer (score 0):

[October 2018 Release notes](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/F/2/BF2F7F86-F908-414C-8982-340658F0076F/BusinessApplications_ReleaseNotes_October18.pdf#page91) talks about deeper integration of entitlements between D365 offerings namely Field service & Sales (work order). There may be background automations happening to achieve this & Workflow is part of it.

> **Entitlement management**
>
> With this release, the Field Service application includes the ability to define entitlements and associate
> them with work orders in field service scenarios. Entitlements help
> service agents understand the service terms that customers are
> eligible for.
>
> This capability helps service organizations ensure
> customers receive the appropriate on-site support that aligns with
> their allowed entitlements, and that customers are charged according
> to their negotiated terms.